# ¿Por qué sólo puedo acceder a los valores de un array asociativo en php por un indice númerico?

Tags: php, poo

He estado practicando con php la orientación a objetos, las consultas a base de datos y la conexión de archivos php y js por ajax.

Me surgió un problema que no he podido solucionarlo, para mi es muy extraño. Trabajando con un array asociativo de php, intento guardar información que luego será enviada a un archivo *js*. Resulta que en el navegador me da errores de índices no definidos, cuando intento imprimir valores del arreglo.

Tratando de resolver el problema, descubrí que al poner un número en el índice en vez del valor en string que le había asignado al índice del arreglo, podía acceder a los valores del mismo. Adjunto el código de una clase utilizada y del `main`.

**indexAction.php**

```
<?php
include 'sitioTuristico.php';
$arr_Sits = array();  //Arreglo con todos los sitios existentes

//Devuelve al script js el archivo json con el resultado de la consulta
echo json_encode($arr_Sits);

function crear_sitios(){
  $i=1;
  while(true) {

    if ($i<10)
      $sitio = new sitioTuristico("SI0".$i); //Creacion de sitios para id's menores a 10
    else
      $sitio = new sitioTuristico("SI".$i);  //Creacion de sitios para id's menores a 10

    if($sitio->getID_SI()=="INEX") //El valor INEX indica que la creacion del sitio turistico no fue exitosa, por lo tanto, se leyeron todos.
      return $arr_Sits;

    $arr_Sits[] = array('ID_SI'=>$sitio->getID_SI(),
                        'URL'=>$sitio->getPrimerURL());
    //$arr_Sits[] = $obj;
    //echo $sitio->getID_SI();
    //var_dump($sitio->getPrimerURL());
    var_dump($arr_Sits['ID_SI']);
    $i++;
  }
}
?>
```

**sitioTuristico.php**

```
<?php
  class sitioTuristico{
    private $ID_SI;                 //String
    private $Nombre;                //String
    private $Descripcion;           //String
    private $Contador_Visitas;      //int
    private $Contador_Comentarios;  //int
    private $Promedio_Nota;         //int
    private $Latitud;               //Double
    private $Longitud;              //Double
    private $Nombre_Cat;            //String
    private $Nombre_Ciu;            //String
    private $Nombre_AD_Creador;     //String
    private $Nombre_AD_Destructor;  //String
    private $URLS;                  //Arreglo

            //---------Constructor de clase---------//
    public function __construct($id_Sit){
      /*Para llenar los atributos del objeto se deben
        de hacer consultas en la base de datos de
        Conce Tour*/

      //Conecta el servidor, si es que hay error, lo notifica
      if (!$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
        print 'No pudo conectarse a mysql';
        exit;
      }

      //Selecciona la base de datos del sitio dentro del servidor.
      if (!mysql_select_db('concetourv1', $conexion)) {
        print 'No pudo seleccionar la base de datos concetour';
        exit;
      }

      //Con la consulta se extrae toda la informacion asociada al sitio turistico
      $query_info = "select DISTINCT s1.ID_SI,s1.Nombre,s1.Descripcion,s1.Contador_Visitas,s1.Contador_Comentarios,s1.Promedio_nota,s1.Latitud,s1.Longitud,i1.URL,ci1.Nombre_Ciu,c1.Nombre_Cat,a1.Nombre as 'Nombre_Creador'
                     from `sitio turistico` s1, categoria c1, imagenes i1, ciudad ci1, administrador a1
                     where s1.ID_SI='".$id_Sit."' and c1.ID_Cat = s1.ID_Cat and i1.ID_SI = s1.ID_SI and ci1.ID_Ciu = s1.ID_Ciu and s1.ID_AD_Creador = a1.ID_AD";

      $info = mysql_query($query_info) or die("Error en $query_info: ".mysql_error());

      if(mysql_num_rows($info)==0){
        $this->ID_SI = "INEX";
        return;
      }
      //URLS se convierte en array. Esto es para manejar las 4 urls existentes.
      $this->URLS = array();

      //Se define toda la información del sitio a partir de los resultados arrojados por la consulta
      $obj = mysql_fetch_object($info);
        $this->ID_SI = $obj->ID_SI;
        $this->Nombre = $obj->Nombre;
        $this->Descripcion = $obj->Descripcion;
        $this->Contador_Visitas = $obj->Contador_Visitas;
        $this->Contador_Comentarios = $obj->Contador_Comentarios;
        $this->Promedio_Nota = $obj->Promedio_nota;
        $this->Latitud = $obj->Latitud;
        $this->Longitud = $obj->Longitud;
        $this->Nombre_Ciu =  $obj->Nombre_Ciu;
        $this->Nombre_Cat =  $obj->Nombre_Cat;
        $this->Nombre_Creador =  $obj->Nombre_Creador;
        $this->URL[] = array('0' => $obj->URL);

      $obj = mysql_fetch_object($info);
        $this->URL[] = array('1' => $obj->URL);

      $obj = mysql_fetch_object($info);
        $this->URL[] = array('2' => $obj->URL);

      $obj = mysql_fetch_object($info);
        $this->URL[] = array('3' => $obj->URL);

      //Verificando la existencia de un administrador destructor
      $queryDest = "select a1.Nombre
                    from `sitio turistico` s1,administrador a1
                    where s1.ID_SI='".$id_Sit."' and s1.ID_AD_Destructor = a1.ID_AD";

      $infoAD = mysql_query($queryDest) or die("Error en $queryDest: ".mysql_error());

      if(mysql_num_rows($infoAD)==0)
        $this->ID_AD_Destructor = NULL;

      else{
        $obj = mysql_fetch_object($infoAD);
        $this->ID_AD_Destructor = $obj->Nombre;
      }

      //Cerrando conexion
      mysql_close($conexion);
    }
            //---------Fin de constructor de clase---------//

            //---------Sección getters---------//
    public function getID_SI()
      { return $this->ID_SI; }

    public function getNombre()
      { return $this->Nombre; }

    public function getContador_Visitas()
      { return $this->Descripcion; }

    public function getContador_Comentarios()
      { return $this->Contador_Comentarios; }

    public function getPromedio_Nota()
      { return $this->Promedio_Nota; }

    public function getLatitud()
      { return $this->Latitud; }

    public function getLongitud()
      { return $this->Longitud; }

    public function getNombre_Cat()
      { return $this->Nombre_Cat; }

    public function getNombre_Ciu()
      { return $this->Nombre_Ciu; }

    public function getNombre_AD_Creador()
      { return $this->Nombre_AD_Creador; }

    public function getNombre_AD_Destructor()
      { return $this->Nombre_AD_Creador; }

    public function getURLS()
      { return $this->URLS; }
          //---------Fin de sección getters---------//

          //---------Sección getters especiales---------//

    //Obtiene la URL de la imágen principal
    public function getPrimerURL(){
      return $this->URL["0"];
    }
        //---------Fin sección getters especiales---------//

          //---------Sección setters---------//
    public function setContador_Visitas()
      { $this->ContadorVisitas++; }

      //---------Fin de sección setters---------//

  }//Fin clase
?>
```

Comment: Los arrays Asociativos están compuesto básicamente por `clave` y  `valor `, sí le asignas como clave un `String` y luego intentar acceder a él mediante un entero te dará error lógicamente. así que la forma de acceder a los elementos mediante la clave será como lo definiste anteriormente (Int o String)

Comment: Es extraño, pero me ocurre lo contrario. El array lo cree con indices de tipo string pero no puedo acceder a ellos por esa via, y lo digo porque lo intente imprimir con print's,echo's y var_dump's y me arrojaba el error de indice no definido, intente lo mismo con un indice numerico y si accedia al valor.

Comment: Qué error le muestra, y a que Array se refiere (En su código)

Comment: el array es $arr_Sits[] y el error es de "indice no definido en ID_SI"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque tú al momento de llenar tu `array` Asociativo `$arr_Sits` no lo haces de `clave->valor` lo haces de forma `Array(clave->valor)` al hacer así el indice será un `int` automáticamente si agregas `1` valor tendrás algo así

`Array (*[0]* => Array ( [ID_SI] => "valor" [URL] => "valor")`
Lo que está entre `* *` será tu clave de acceso al **Array** más no al `valor` por eso el error de `indice indefinido` ya que los indices de los `Arrays` dentro del tu Array Padre`($arr_Sits)` son enteros y no cadenas.

Para acceder al valor tendrías que acceder al `Indice`(**int**) y luego a la `clave`

```
echo $arr_Sits[0]['ID_SI'];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, eso queria lograr con el array pero no sabia que estaba haciendo. Había visto este tipo de arrays en python como diccionarios, pero no les habia considerado el potencial que tienen. Muy util!